# Incrementing int by check marking a radio button

Tags: javascript

I have a whole bunch of radio buttons formatted in the following way;

`<input type="radio" name="Xch" value="XCheese " onclick="incrementIndex()">XCheese<br>`

and my `incrementIndex()` function is simple enough;

```
var index = 0;

function incrementIndex() {
    index += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""+index+"";

    if ($("#Xch").attr("checked") == true){
        index = 10;
    }
}
```

And when a radiobutton is clicked it increments the index, but I want it to increase the index once and only if the button is not checked, the way it is set up, even if the Xch radio button is checked, it keeps increment the index! Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do something like this, but is this what you were trying to do?

```
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="XCheese " onclick="incrementIndex(this)">XCheese</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="YCheese " onclick="incrementIndex(this)">YCheese</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="ZCheese " onclick="incrementIndex(this)">ZCheese</input><br>


var index = 0;
var previousValue;
function incrementIndex(e)
{    
    if(e.checked && e != previousValue) index += 1;
    previousValue = e;
    alert(index);
}
```

Here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Md8fj/134/

Comment: The example is great, however it is not working on my app, perhaps the reason is that I have the script in the body?

Comment: Strange. It should still work there. You can use your browser's developer tools (F12 in most browswers, I think) to see if you're getting any javascript errors. You can also add an `alert(1);` to the top of your function to make sure the function is being called

Comment: SOrry it works like a charm, I forgot to add e to the method's constructor and "this" to the radio button's tag

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't exactly clear, but if you want the desired behavior, move the `index += 1` inside the if statement that detects if it's already checked. If it's not, then you can increment.

Something like:

```
var index = 0;

function incrementIndex() {

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ""+index+"";

    if ($("#Xch").attr("checked") == true){
        index = 10;
    }
    else {
        index += 1;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesn't even change the index, increment or set to 10, is it because the script is in the body of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `checkbox` instead of a `radiobox`.
In a radio group, once an input is selected, one input in the group must always remain selected.
In a checkbox group, any number if inputs can be selected or deselected.

Change your HTML to:

`<input type="checkbox" name="Xch" value="XCheese " onclick="incrementIndex()">XCheese<br>`

And it should work.

Comment: That will still result in the value being incremented even if the widget is already checked. An onclick will fire any time the widget is clicked, not just if it's not checked.